# I've got PHP Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed when I use phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I've got a problem when I trying to send an email by using **PHPMailer**, and I'm following this tutorial https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-use-phpmailer/134686 because I use **000webhost** for my website for free.

PHP code:

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mail/Exception.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mail/PHPMailer.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mail/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // use $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
$mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl is deprecated
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'youremail@gmail.com'; // email
$mail->Password = 'PASSWORD'; // password
$mail->setFrom('system@cksoftwares.com', 'CKSoftwares System'); // From email and name
$mail->addAddress('to@address.com', 'Mr. Brown'); // to email and name
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("test body"); //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported'; // If html emails is not supported by the receiver, show this body
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                    )
                );
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

But when I try it exactly, I got an error like this:

```
2022-03-29 14:56:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-03-29 14:56:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection c27-20020a05620a165b00b0067d32238bc8sm9217183qko.125 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

And thanks for helping.

Comment: The last part of that tutorial is wrong. You don't need to enable IMAP in Gmail for this to work, because this code is using SMTP not IMAP

Comment: You need to enable "less secure apps"...but note that this is being switched off on 30th May 2022, so this solution won't work for long. Find another SMTP provider you can use instead, or consider using the Gmail API or a 3rd party mail service. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 for details.

Comment: I've enabled "less secure apps" before, but it's still not working. should I enable something like "SMTP" or what? because I want to continue with gmail or this way. and thank you

Comment: `because I want to continue with gmail`...as I've already explained, you can't continue with it beyond 30th May anyway, so this isn't going to be a good solution for you. There isn't a separate "SMTP" option you can enable, it's done via the less secure apps feature, but this will cease to work. Google is not trying to run a public SMTP server.

Comment: I already mentioned that you can use the GMail HTTP API, or you can find another SMTP service to use, or you can find a 3rd party mail API - there are several on the market.

Comment: Thanks for your help, are you saying I can never work this way and it's incorrect or is there any hope of it working? (Bear with me a little my language is not strong to understand you well)

Comment: It means the Gmail SMTP service will stop working for everyone on 30th May. So yes you need to find an alternative way to send emails. I have suggested some alternatives.

Comment: You may also be able to use the App Password login method to continue accessing the SMTP service though. This is similar to what outlook.com allows, actually

Comment: No, the SMTP service will not stop working. As the doc that @ADyson linked to earlier says, you can continue to use conventional auth with gmail after the cutoff by using [app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en), but you can also continue to use SMTP by using XOAUTH2 authentication, which [PHPMailer supports](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2), and there is a new alternative using [Google API libs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Gmail-XOAUTH2-Using-Google-API-Client#using-phpmailer-66x-and-googleapiclient-2x).

Comment: @Synchro sorry yes I meant that SMTP will stop working via the Less Secure Apps feature. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much a lot for your time!